# How can I embed a website regardless of the user's hosts file / dns resolver?

Tags: html, linux, apache, .htaccess, iframe

Think of a website with a few embedded stuff from facebook.com.

How can I force everything from facebook.com be loaded from 1.1.1.1 instead of their servers, without touching a user's hosts file or dns, when they access this particular website?

Comment: You can't. If you were able to do that, web security would not exist as we know it

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a machine on the same network, then it may be possible to do an arp cache poisoning attack, so that the victim's machine thinks your machine is the gateway, and therefore it routes all of it's upstream traffic through your machine.  Then, (using wireshark or a similar program running on your machine) you can essentially do a 'man-in-the-middle' attack, and modify http traffic any way you want.  But, as mvp alludes, this is much easier to do with http traffic.  With https traffic, it's much more complicated (although still possible due to security weaknesses in PKI) because you will need to fake a certificate.  For this, you will need a tool like sslstrip or sslsniff.